# Is an object valid in serialized form? c++/inheritance/serialization

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I'm asking this because even tho it seems to work, I feel like it shouldn't. The goal is to have a collection of objects kept alive, and general access to them. This is what I have at the moment:

Take a base pointer access:

```
struct base { virtual void tick() = 0; }; //ptr access
```

With different types that inherit from it:

```
struct :public base
{
    void tick() { cout << "im type 1" << endl; }
}type1;

struct :public base
{
    void tick() { cout << "im type 2" << endl; }
}type2;
```

Then a container class that should be able to store any amount of these serialized:

```
class control
{
    struct xtype //struct for organizing objects
    {
        vector<char>charbuf; //serialized object
    }xtype_template;

    vector<xtype>xtype_vec;

public:

    template<typename T> base* tell_to(T &input) //take object, return (base*)
    { 
        xtype_template.charbuf.resize(sizeof(input));
        memcpy(xtype_template.charbuf.data(), (char*)&input, sizeof(input));

        xtype_vec.push_back(xtype_template);  //push back with template after filling

        return (base*)xtype_vec[xtype_vec.size() - 1].charbuf.data(); //pointer to data
    }  
}xcontainer; //container object
```

Then call:

```
auto ptr = controller.tell_to(type1); //becomes base* 
auto ptr2 = controller.tell_to(type2);
```

And you can access either static-sized serialized object, as well as its states, by doing:

```
ptr->tick(); //which will output "im type 1" to console
ptr2->tick() //"im type 2"
```

But is this legal? Do these serialized versions have an actual type? Is accessing a serialized object directly with a base pointer illegal or wrong?

---

Closest probable answer: as the return on [is_trivially_copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) show false, objects might not be safe to manage after getting base inheritance.

Follow up: This approach seems to work, and fiddling with `is_trivially_copyable`, seems to suggest that making an object inherit methods from, makes it unsafe. Basic methods do not make it unsafe however, and that makes me wonder if the safety only applies to exporting between systems, saving to file, or transferring over the network. Maybe the check just assumes the virtual reference makes them unsafe?

Follow up 2: If the characters remain in the same spot in memory, does it matter how they are accessed? Id wager that the only real problem with this approach, is if the objects stored were to have elements that would change their size after being stored.

Comment: I want to have a collection of different objects in a vector (of vectors). The idea is to store function-objects that tell the container what tick() should do, or to generalize access to methods across types, if that makes sense

Comment: like vector<unique_ptr<base>>objs_owner; ? hm I dont think im familiar with this approach. It wont slice the objects?

Comment: See my answer, my original comment was wrong.

Comment: Im not convinced this approach is unsafe for the purpose im using it for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing is illegal. You can only `memcpy` an object as an array of `char`s when the object is `TriviallyCopyable`. And your object is not, since it has virtual functions.

Instead of doing this, you should simply store a (unique) pointer to newly allocated object, and avoid any casts to enforce hierarchy. Like this:

```
class xtype
{
    std::unique_ptr<base> ptr;

public:

    template<typename T> base* serial_acc(T &input) //take object, return (base*)
    { 
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<base, T>::value, "Please use proper type");
        ptr = std::make_unique<base>(input);
        return ptr;
    }  
} xcontainer;
```

Comment: Also, besides being `TriviallyCopyable`, you can only cast the `char`s back to a pointer to the object if the `char`s are properly aligned for the type (or else you have to copy them back to an aligned storage).

Comment: @AndréSassi, while generally correct, alignment is implementation defined, and major implementations on major platforms support unaligned access.

Comment: I'm still not convinced this is unsafe for what I'm trying to do. It might be unsafe for networking and exporting to files, but privately like this? @SergeyA

Comment: @Charlie, yes, it is unsafe and completely bizarre. You still didn't explain why you need this.

Comment: Im trying to accomplish a few different things. This is just part of that, being able to store different objects in 1 container, and then cycle through their methods, as if they were the same. Ideally, i could just do this: vector<generic_method_ptr*>any_method_queue; and pass it any method pointer

Comment: the answer is yours :D after some punishing hours in c++ lounge @SergeyA

Answer (score 0):

Working example given by user [Andy Prowl](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1932150)

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct base 
{
    virtual void tick() = 0; 
};

struct type1 : base
{
    virtual void tick() override { cout << "im type 1"<<endl; }
};

struct type2 : base
{
    virtual void tick() override { cout << "im type 2" << endl; }
};

struct controller
{
    vector<unique_ptr<base>> objects; 

    void cycle_tick(){ for (auto const& ptr : objects)ptr->tick();}

    void add_object(unique_ptr<base> obj){ objects.emplace_back(move(obj));}

};

int main()
{
    auto t1 = unique_ptr<type1>(new type1);
    auto t2 = unique_ptr<type2>(new type2);

    controller ctrl_object;
    c.add_object(move(t1));
    c.add_object(move(t2));

    ctrl_object.cycle();
}
```